# Private Proxy Registry for DockerHub, GCR, ECR, ACR and Quay.io

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is there anyway to proxy or mirror the following Docker registries with my own Private Docker Registry?

- Google Container Registry
- AWS EC2 Container Registry
- Azure Container Registry
- Quay.io
- DockerHub

I want to use a Private Registry to store all Docker Images I need. 
I want to pull Images without changing the `repo/image:tag` name when doing a docker pull? For example, with Nexus if I want to do a:

`docker pull gcr.io/google_containers/metrics-server-amd64:v0.2.1`

I must change the repo name:

`docker pull mynexus.mycompany.com/google_containers/metrics-server-amd64:v0.2.1`

Is there any docker/kubernetes config that says if someeone does a pull if a `gcr.io` Image just go to `mynexus.mycompany.com` instead and use as a pass thru cache.

Comment: Doing docker cache for registry https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/registry/recipes/mirror.md you can do the same

Answer (score 1):

GCR, ECR, ACR and Quay.io not supported current docker

Try this proxy

https://github.com/rpardini/docker-registry-proxy

https://github.com/rpardini/docker-caching-proxy-multiple-private

Answer (score 0):

In Sonatype Nexus,

1. [create a "docker (proxy)" repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/docker-registry/proxy-repository-for-docker).
2. [create a "docker (group)" repository](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/nexus-repository-administration/formats/docker-registry/grouping-docker-repositories).
3. In the group, repository, add both the proxy and any hosted repos

You should now be able to refer to the group repository URL, qualified with your image names and tags, to retrieve any image in any repository that the group can see. You will need to set-up individual proxies for each of GCR, Quay, etc. Also, your image build processes will need to push to the one of your hosted repositories, NOT to the group repository. You push to your hosted, and pull from your group.